# How can I know which interrupt line is shared or not, and which interrupt line is free in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I am going to write a PCIe base serial I/O card driver in Linux.

As per my knowledge through the configuration space, it provides the interrupt line, and through the `IRQF_SHARED` flag we are able to share the interrupt handler with that corresponding `IRQ` line.

But my confusion is how can I know which line is shared or not shared?

Comment: It'll be easier to read if you don't use *ALL CAPS*.

Comment: through the cat /proc/interrupts I can see but apart from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel-assisted probing

The Linux kernel offers a low-level facility for probing the interrupt number. It works
for only nonshared interrupts, but most hardware that is capable of working in a
shared interrupt mode provides better ways of finding the configured interrupt num-
ber anyway. The facility consists of two functions, declared in `<linux/interrupt.h>`
(which also describes the probing machinery):

`unsigned long probe_irq_on(void);`

This function returns a bit mask of unassigned interrupts. The driver must pre-
serve the returned bit mask, and pass it to `probe_irq_off` later. After this call, the
driver should arrange for its device to generate at least one interrupt.
`int probe_irq_off(unsigned long);`

After the device has requested an interrupt, the driver calls this function, passing
as its argument the bit mask previously returned by `probe_irq_on`. `probe_irq_off`
returns the number of the interrupt that was issued after “probe_on.” If no inter-
rupts occurred, 0 is returned (therefore, IRQ 0 can’t be probed for, but no cus-
tom device can use it on any of the supported architectures anyway). If more than
one interrupt occurred (ambiguous detection), `probe_irq_off` returns a negative
value.

The programmer should be careful to enable interrupts on the device after the call to
`probe_irq_on` and to disable them before calling `probe_irq_off`. Additionally, you
must remember to service the pending interrupt in your device after `probe_irq_off`.

Answer (score 2):

For a device driver, there is no useful way (and especially no portable way) to find out if the interrupt line is actually shared, and this could change at any time by loading/unloading other drivers.
PCI drivers must always assume that their interrupt might be shared.

Note: PCI Express devices are supposed to support MSIs (message-signaled interrupts), which are never shared.
Your driver should enable MSIs if at all possible.
However, it is not guaranteeed that the system supports them.

Comment: +1.  Just call `pci_enable_msi()` on your device, and if successful, you can omit IRQF_SHARED in `request_irq()`.  Otherwise, include it.

Answer (score 0):

Run `cat /proc/interrupt`. In the rightmost column of the output you should see your device on one of the interrupts lines.  If it's shared you'll see other devices assigned to that interrupt as well.